# Null Handling in SQL Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, null, conditional-statements, dynamic-queries

I have the following table:

[All records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/darqJ.jpg)

I want to get records satisfying some set of conditions.

Below is the query and it returns 3 results:

[Records satisfying query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UFlb.jpg)

Now I want records which did not satisfy remaining records (i.e. records which did not satisfy conditions in the previous query) and I expect total 4 rows in return. So I am executing the query:

[Query for remaining records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gNRP.jpg)

However, record number 4 is not returned and I know that col2 values 'null' is causing this problem.

I even tried with NVL and coalesce function but without any luck:

[nvl_coalesce_queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhanV.jpg)

So basically, I want 4 rows in 'NOT' query.

Please let me know if any suggestions.

Comment: Please don’t post queries or code as images. They’re text so post them as such. Please edit the question and include them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : Data is getting misaligned when posted as text.

Comment: See the [**formatting help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). To generate tables you can use [this](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) or simply copy & paste the `psql` output

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
select *
from tmp_dbg3
where col0 not in (select col0 from tmp_dbg3 where <your 'satisfying' condition>)
```

Comment: That's a valid answer and returns expected result.  Similarly using MINUS operator also, we can get this results. **However, what I am looking for is is there a way we can handle null values in query itself and not required to query based on col0 again?** Reason being this is a sample code I have provided for scenario. Actual query is querying on pretty large data-sets. So 'NOT IN' operation will degrade performance.

Comment: You definitely can handle null values if do it explicitly. You should replace, say, `col1 in ('1')` with `col1 is not null and col1 in ('1')` and so on.

Comment: Thnks for the suggestion. My actual query is following. ( ( tt.TRAN_TYPE IN
  ( SELECT RULE_VALUE FROM GP_RULE_VALUE WHERE RULE_ID=1332 )
AND tt.CONTRACT IN
  ( SELECT RULE_VALUE FROM GP_RULE_VALUE WHERE RULE_ID=1333 )
AND tt.CUSTOMER_STATE NOT IN
  ( SELECT RULE_VALUE FROM GP_RULE_VALUE WHERE RULE_ID=1334))
  **I want to make sure tt.* columns are not null then only check. This query is generated dynamically and tt.* columns can be known  only after above query is generated.  Is there a regexp_replace I can use to add 'tt.column_name is not null and tt.column name in ...'?**

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, there is such regexp. If you'll fail to make it yourself, I guess, it should be better to ask it in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out REGEXP_REPLACE required

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [NOT IN operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189062(v=sql.105).aspx):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189062(v=sql.105).aspx

```
SELECT * FROM database
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM database WHERE  *your conditions*)
```

I am assuming that the first column in your database is the auto increment key.  I would personally prefer to use that to identify which columns are not in your conditions instead of col1.